# не работает цветной текст в visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

я использую visual studio + пайтон. Написал такой код(я экспериментирую):

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

err = """the
"""
print(Fore.RED + err)
```

Но он выводит не окрашенный текст the. Как это исправить? У меня windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio запускает ваш код но не умеет подсвечивать результат.

Просто нужно запускать вашу программу из терминала (можно и из Visual Studio'вского), вот так:

```sh
python <ИМЯ ФАЙЛА>
```

Должно заработать.

Comment: Я понял, но можно настроить visual studio чтобы он умел?

Comment: @Hub скорее всего нельзя, у меня нет VS но по логике догадался что из терминала запускать надо.